# Does German distinguish between /t͡s/ and /ts/?

Tags: phonetics

Do you pronounce differently Platsfuehrer and Plazfuehrer?

Comment: Could you please explain what those words are supposed to mean?

Comment: @Stephie I have no idea, just constructed them. Other possible examples: Ganzfuehrer vs. Ghantsfuehrer.

Comment: Please use existing words. Otherwise it's a purely hypothetic question.

Comment: I currently do not find a *real* minimal pair, but perhaps a more *realistic* minimal pair might be "Schuttsauge" (might be a rubble sucking device) vs "Schutzauge" (might be a protective eye). Pronunciation of these differs by stops introduced between syllables. On the other hand, "hat's" and "Hatz" are pronounced identically.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen thanks. This might be a good answer.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: That a word is written with *"ts"* does not mean that it should not be pronounced as /t͡s/. *Arbeitsamt, Staatsoper* and many other words are written with *"ts"* that is pronounced the same way as if it was written with *"z".* But maybe there are still words where *"ts"* is spoken as /ts/.

Comment: You can't establish phonemes by looking at the spelling. <ä> and <e> stand for the same phoneme in *hätte, Kette*, yet <e> stands for two different phonemes in *Weg, weg*.

Comment: I don't quite get why this question attracts so many downvotes. If asking about how a combination of letters is pronounced it makes sense to put them into otherwise identical context. An answer then can be (as Hubert shows) that context does matter while showing that the different letter sequences are otherwise pronounced the same, if context is identical

Comment: @planetmaker I didn't downvote. But I understand that such a poorly elaborated question (Platsfuehrer and Plazfuehrer?) attracts downvotes.

Comment: @planetmaker It's equivalent to asking how to pronounce "flought". It's not an existing word and could be pronounced like "fought" or like "drought" for all we know.

Answer (score 7):

[t͡s] is one doubly articulated consonant.
[ts] are two separate articulated consonants.

When the sounds [t] and [s] appear inside the same syllable, they are always pronounced as [t͡s], no matter if they are written as »z«, »tz«, »ts« or as »t«:

- tz

  - [plötzlich](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/pl%C3%B6tzlich) = [ˈplœt͡slɪç]
  - [schätzen](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/sch%C3%A4tzen) = [ˈʃɛt͡sn̩]
  - [Platz](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Platz) = [plat͡s]
- z

  - [zu](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/zu) = [t͡suː]
  - [zwei](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/zwei) = [t͡svaɪ̯]
  - [Prozent](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Prozent) = [pʁoˈt͡sɛnt]
- ts

  - [bereits](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/bereits) = [bəˈʁaɪ̯t͡s]
  - [stets](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/stets) = [ʃteːt͡s]
  - [rechts](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/rechts) = [ʁɛçt͡s]
- t

  - [Information](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Information) = [ɪnfɔʁmaˈt͡si̯oːn]
  - [Aktion](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Aktion) = [akˈt͡si̯oːn]
  - [Munition](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Munition) = [muniˈt͡si̯oːn]

But if [t] and [s] belong to two different syllables, they have to be pronounced separately. And because in southern regions like Austria and Bavaria the sound [z] is almost always spoken as [s], you have at least in Austrian pronunciation a lot of words with [ts]:

- [Tatsache](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Tatsache) = [ˈtaːtˌsaxə]
- [gewaltsam](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/gewaltsam) = [ɡəˈvaltsaːm]
- [entsenden](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/entsenden) = [ɛntˈsɛndn̩]

But note, that all examples given here are pronounced with [tz] in northern regions of German sprachraum ([ˈtaːtˌzaxə], [ɡəˈvaltzaːm], [ɛntˈzɛndn̩].